# Vue2 invalid css in main.js file

Tags: vuejs2

I have a project on github, I work on it at home where it works fine, but when I pull it onto another pc and run the necessary commands it fails on the module build.

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import SuiVue from 'semantic-ui-vue';
import './assets/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css'
import './assets/sass/main.scss'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
});

Vue.use(SuiVue);
```

The invalid css error I get when I run **npm run dev**:

```
Module build failed: 
import Vue from 'vue'
^
      Invalid CSS after "i": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "import Vue from 'vu"
      in /Users/Developer/www/profile-site/src/main.js (line 1, column 1)

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

Not sure if I am missing something somewhere when I pull in the project.

Here is the actual repository: https://github.com/RduPlessis/profile-site

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to solve it?